# Ordered weighted averaging error: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, saga, weighted-overlay

I am trying to perform an ordered weighted average on two rasters in QGIS 3.0.3 (as a trial run for doing it on more than two rasters). But I keep receiving the following error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.0/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\saga\SagaAlgorithm.py", line 275, in processAlgorithm
s = values[i] + '\t' + values[i + 1] + '\t' + values[i + 2] + '\n'
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

Execution failed after 0.05 seconds

I googled the error message but my programming knowledge is limited.
I first thought that it could be because the rasters were of different types so I converted both to UInt16 (Raster->Conversion->Translate) but I am still getting the same error. I am not sure what to try now to fix the problem.

Here is some background information on the rasters and the project I am working on:

- I am trying to produce an overall risk map considering the relative contribution of various factors (e.g. rivers, roads).
- Each raster contains buffer zones around one factor (e.g. roads).
- Each buffer zone is assigned an integer value representing the level of risk (0= no data, 1= no risk, ..., 7=high risk).
- For this trial run I was attempting to weight two layers at 60, 40.
- One layer had integers from 0-5, the other had integers from 1-7.
- The rasters are single band, and tif format.

Comment: Looks like a bug in the QGIS Processing implementation for SAGA's Ordered weighted averaging tool. Please report it in the QGIS bug tracker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been fixed in QGIS 3.2.0 Bonn (it was a bug in the code).